# Application freezing AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to consult with the code. I'm writing amateur "game" and everything still went, but I have a problem with the fact that the main Frame, the code is probably too long and the flash of a certain length in the debugger freezes.

Specifically, I have a lot MovieClip frame for which changes their visibility then any one timer and some type of conditions if / else statements and functions to mouse clicks replacing buttons. I know it's not written very well, but I'm an amateur programming. I would be glad if you help me to find something that would help me reduce application complexity, so I was forced to quit just before the goal. Maybe there's something I could write like that. to stop the program freeze. Thanks.

Here is a sample code of main frame:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
if (pavelON == true) {
            pavel2.visible = true;
    } else {
            pavel2.visible = false;
    }
if (petrON == true) {
            petr2.visible = true;
    } else {
            petr2.visible = false;
    }
if (martinON == true) {
            martin2.visible = true;
    } else {
            martin2.visible = false;
    }
if (zdencaON == true) {
            zdenca2.visible = true;
    } else {
            zdenca2.visible = false;
    }
if (danON == true) {
            dan2.visible = true;
    } else {
            dan2.visible = false;
    }
if (paziON == true) {
            pazi2.visible = true;
    } else {
            pazi2.visible = false;
    }
var countDownDec:Number = 1;
var totalSecs = 0;
var countDownSecs = totalSecs;
cas.text = countDownSecs;
var time:Timer = new Timer(countDownDec*1000);
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
function tick(e:TimerEvent):void {
    if (countDownSecs == 120) {
            trace("count down complete");
            time.stop();
            countDownSecs = totalSecs;
    } else {
            countDownSecs = countDownSecs + countDownDec;
            cas.text = countDownSecs;
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startTimer);
function startTimer(e:Event):void {
            if(time.running == true) {
                    } else {
                    cas.text = totalSecs;
                    time.start();
            }
    }
var mcnm:Number = 2;
var mcnf:Number = 0;
var mcnt:Number = 0;
var hm:Number = 0;
mcnmt.text = mcnm.toString();
mcnft.text = mcnf.toString();
mcntt.text = mcnt.toString();
hmt.text = hm.toString();
pavel2.stop();
petr2.stop();
martin2.stop();
zdenca2.stop();
dan2.stop();
pazi2.stop();
pavel_prace.visible = false;
petr_prace.visible = false;
martin_prace.visible = false;
zdenca_prace.visible = false;
dan_prace.visible = false;
pazi_prace.visible = false;
upozorneni.visible = false;
var pavel2ON:Boolean = false;
var petr2ON:Boolean = false;
var martin2ON:Boolean = false;
var zdenca2ON:Boolean = false;
var dan2ON:Boolean = false;
var pazi2ON:Boolean = false;
upozorneni.zavrit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,zavriClick);
function zavriClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    upozorneni.visible = false;}
pavel2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pavelClick);
function pavelClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
        if ((pavel2ON == false)&&(mcnm > 0)){
                pavel_prace.visible =true;
```

Because it is the contribution of the limited length of the text the code is then here:
http://www.filedropper.com/code_4

I attach a SWF file that you can see the function. https://ulozto.cz/!ab4C1i5yTJKG/kollmorgen3-swf (pass: "pomoc")
The end got in parentheses intentionally, because without them now it freezes. I do not know the limits of Adobe Flash CS5.5.

Comment: I doubt your code is too long. But the more code you have, the more chances you've typed something wrong and that can certainly cause an error

Comment: Why the `uporzanini.` before the `zavrit`? but nothing's similar before the `pavel`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing it to freeze, but you also ask for help simplifying the code (which will make it easier to read and eventually find the problem) so try this:

Add similar elements to an array and then loop through that array for similar operations like this:

```
var cArray:Array = new Array();
cArray.push(petr2);
cArray.push(pavel2);
//...etc.
// then you can loop through them when needed
for (var i:int=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
    cArray.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click);

    if (cArray[i]._on == true){
        cArray[i].visible = true;
    } else {
        cArray[i].visible = false;
    }
    cArray[i].stop();
}
function click(me:MouseEvent):void{
    if (me.target._on == //etc... hopefully you get the gist by now
```

You will need to add a property to your character class called `_on` for this to work.

But I surmise that you aren't using custom classes, which you probably ought to learn to do now and make things easy on yourself. But you can see that I have replaced a bunch of your repetitive code with a simple array and loop and a single `click` function. This is advantageous for readability as well as maintainability (imagine adding a new character... you'd just have to add him to the array and your done... You don't have to update all those other bits of code)

As a less simple but maybe more accessible method (no need for custom classes) you can use an array of associated values like this:

```
var cArray:Array = new Array();
cArray.push({character:pavel2, status:"on"});
```

then you could change the status of `pavel2._on` by doing `cArray[i].status = "off"` and access `pavel2` itself by doing. `cArray[i].character`.